# URL redirection issue

Tags: cms, url-rewrite, cms-pages

I have a webshop wherein :

- **abc.com/staff** is giving **page not found error**
- **abc.com/staff/** is loading the page correctly.

There is a difference of "/" in both the URLS.
I have other CMS pages in magento such as contact-us which are working perfectly fine.
Need assistance in this scenario about what is going wrong.

Comment: If any other information is required do let me know ? No assistance so far .